# How to measure total execution time in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

There are many dataflow which include many flowflies,and i want to measure their total execution time.What can i do?
[image]
Any help is appreciate！！！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `UpdateAttribute` processor with the Ni-Fi function `now` as the [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#now), set the attribute the starttime to `${now()}` and at the final of the code, again update the attribute such as:

```
timediff  ${now():minus(${starttime}):format("HH:mm")}
```

where the code will give you the time difference in a format of hours:minutes to the attribute `timediff`. Then you can print or save or what you want to do with this attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much!As you said,if there are many flowfiles,is it the end time for the last flowfile or the first flowfile?I hope it's the former.

Comment: I think it will be calculated for each flowfile cuz the attribute will be attached into all the flowfiles.

Comment: The question is:How do i know it's the last flowfile with interval?Except keep refreshing and staring at it.Thanks.

Comment: if you split the flowfile it is possible to know what is the last. otherwise, it is not possible as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information from the logs.  If you set the `Bulletin Level` of the processors you want to monitor to `DEBUG` level, for example the GET and PUT processors:

[image]

You will then see debug log messages from each processor you configure, and you can get the time spent from this.

Comment: Thanks!No duration,only end time!Any other suggestion?TIA

Comment: What is the first processor in your flow? (I can't see it in your pic) .. If there is some sort of GET processor, you should see this debug statement which will give the starting time